# 1C. Конфигурация

Tags: 1с

Месяц назад устроилась на завод в IT отдел. Так получилось, что программист 1с уволился и начальник передел мне 1с. До этого я никогда не работала с 1с. Бывший сотрудник оставил свою учетку (Админ) захожу и работаю через его учетку. Решила создать нового пользователя(себя) и назначила роль Админа(позаимствовала у старого админа его роль) но проблема в том что не все доступно мне, выплывают разные ошибки, а когда захожу снова с учетки строго работника(Админа ) все работает. Не понимаю в чем проблема Роль то я использую старого сотрудника (Админа)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1С ХОЧУ РОЛЬ АДМИН( бывшего сотрудника) присвоить себе. но не все права работают как у строго админа, хотя роль одна и та жа

Comment: Какая конфигурация? Скриншоты как создаете пользователя и права присваиваете?

Comment: Случаются ситуации, когда права, роли, возможности в коде привязаны к имени учетной записи. Думаю, стоит это проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это не единственная роль, которая была в учетке бывшего админа. Посмотрите снова права доступа в учетной записи бывшего админа. Если есть другие группы, в которые Вы себя не включили, то попробуйите включить себя в них.
Кроме того, обратите внимание есть ли золотой круг в значке возле профиля группы доступа "Администратор". Такой круг стоит только в оригинальной версии профиля с полными правами.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно достаточно две роли *Администратор , Полные права* ; Если хотите выставить такие же права как у другой учетки, воспользуйтесь советом выше: Откройте учетную запись Админа, запишите все Роли напротив которых стоит галочка, затем в своей учетной записи - отметьте галочкой эти роли;